# Run two commands in CMD and return 0 as long as at least one of them returns 0

Tags: cmd

Title says it all. I just want two know how to run two commands. If either or both of them return `0`, I want to return `0`. Only if both of them return `1` should I return `1`. So basically I want to return `A && B`, where `A` and `B` are two different commands.

P.S. This is not in a batch script this should work typed on the command line please.

Comment: No, the title does not say it all! Neither does your whole question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
((StatementA)&&(StatementB)||(Statement0))||(StatementB)
```

where

- Statement0 always returns 0 (no error) - it prevents executing last StmtB,
- StatementA and StatementB are the two commands you need to run;
- StatementA runs first,
- StatementB (first) runs if StatementA succeeded (returned 0),
- StatementB (last) runs if StatementA failed (returned errorlevel > 0).

Comment: thank you so much, this worked exactly as I asked :)